# How to resolve BufferedReader() with blanks?

Tags: java, char, bufferedreader

Got a problem. Why are the blanks in both opt cases? (By using readLine() it's no problem.)

Thanks!

```
 String srcFile = "d:/javatest/File2String.txt";

 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(srcFile));

 char[] chs = new char[1024];

 int len = 0;

 //opt 1    while ((len = br.read(chs, 0, len)) != -1){   // Why are blanks with no endings???

 //opt 2    while ((len = br.read(chs)) != -1){           // Why are blanks with length of len???

 System.out.println(chs);

 }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "Why are blanks". Please show the expected output of your code and the actual output of your code.

Comment: Thanks Sweeper!
You see a lot of blanks after "This is a test                                  " with opt 2 and
you see lots of blanks on scree with opt 1.
(You might copy to you IDE to see it clearer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `System.out.println(chs);` always prints 1024 characters regardless of how many characters were read into chs. In opt2 you read `len` characters, and print 1024 characters so there will be extra characters in the output when len < 1024 - these are `\0` for small file, or will repeat the value read by the previous iteration for the final loop when filesize > 1024.

In opt1 len is zero initially so you are calling `br.read(chs, 0, 0)` in an infinite loop. You ask to read 0 and get 0 back - len never changes from `0` as each read returns 0 and assigns back to `len`. Each time you print 1024 values of `chs` - all set to `\0`.

You could print the exact chs buffer content each time by looping i= 0 to len and print `System.out.print(chs[i])`, or in one step with `System.out.println(new String(chs, 0, len))` but note that this is duplicating / copying the contents again.

If you simply want to cat/type the file to current console you can do it without BufferedReader with:

```
try(var os = new FileInputStream(srcFile)) {
   os.transferTo(System.out);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot DuncG! 
I wrongly took the error for br.read() for there's no problem with br.readNewLine(), as you pointed out it's println(). Have you got an idea to print on screen with no blanks?Thanks!
And the problem with int len = 0; was that with int len = -1; you'll get "IndexOutOfBoundException'. Some other suggestions to avoid using off-set at br.read() when leave [1024] as default? Thanks again!

Comment: It is easier use `br.read(chs)` as this calls `br.read(chs,0, chs.length)` - so length is always set correctly.

Comment: Great! Both int len = 0; or int len = -1; will work, but 
while ((len = br.read(chs)) != 0) invokes the error "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException".
Franly speaking, I do not catch your sentence "It is easier use br.read(chs) as this calls br.read(chs,0, chs.length) - so length is always set correctly." Do you mean read(chs) is equivalent to read(chs, 0, length) since "0" and "len" are default?
BTW, suggestion with abanding BufferedReader is ingenious! Again many thanks!

Comment: If you have a good IDE: view the code for, or step into `br.read(chs)` and you'll see what I mean.